infinite-scroller refresh in vuetifyjs
After I use the method "done('empty')" in onload, scroll not work any more. For example - I scroll to down, an items end, I scroll to top. And in this time in items push new a rows, I want show them but after scroll down method onload not touch.
Init the scroll
<v-infinite-scroll ref="v_infinite_scroll" :items="items" :onLoad="loadItems">

Onload method
async loadItems ({ done }) {
            
    let data = await api.loadItems;
            
    if (data == null) {
         try {
             done('empty')
             return;
         } catch (error) {
             console.error(error)
         }
             return;
         }

         try {
            done('ok')
            return;
         } catch (error) {
            console.error(error)
         } 
},

I tried use this.$forceUpdate() for rerender the parent component and this.$refs.v_infinite_scroll.$forceUpdate() for rerender the scroll component, but nothing.

The scrolling is assumed to be completely finished when the done function has the status of 'empty' and there is not meant to be a way to get it scrolling again. A workaround is to save a copy of the function before it has 'empty' status which you can then use to reset the original function.
let doneCopy = null

async loadItems ({ done }) {
  let data = await api.loadItems;
  if (data == null) {
    doneCopy = done // save copy
    done('empty')
    return;
  }
  else if (data !== null && doneCopy) {
    doneCopy('ok') // reset original "done" function
    doneCopy = null
  }
  ...
}

